# Super/Alt key combinations making screen go blank

Tags: linux, keyboard, terminal

I started having a weird issue on my Ubuntu Linux with KDE: if I press any of the following combinations:

- (Super or Alt) + left arrow
- (Super or Alt) + right arrow
- (Super or Alt) + any F-key

The key combination works, but my screen goes immediately blank and I have to do `Ctrl+Alt+F7` to return to the desktop. Other than that, the Alt, Super and arrow keys work normally (e.g. Alt+Tab).

I don't remember having changed any settings which could cause this, but I may have accidentally activated it after having issues<sup>1</sup> with an US international keyboard with dead keys.

Is there a way to check if there are keyboard shortcuts associated to a "blank screen" command? I searched a bit on KDE's settings but found nothing that seemed to indicate an accidental change.

<sup>1</sup>
The original issue I had (which is possibly related) was: from time to time, my Konsole goes nuts and I can no longer type double quote (`"`) or apostrophe (`'`), but **only** on Konsole, it works as normal in every other program (including other terminals, such as `xterm` and `gnome-terminal`). In Konsole (either an existing process, or a new one), these keys become `¨` and `´` (normally I have to type them twice to obtain these characters) and I cannot enter the original characters. I searched around and found some websites recommending combinations of `kbd_mode -a` and `setxkbmap` that would reset Konsole's behavior, and it worked for some days, but this time it didn't work. And shortly after that, this "blank screen" thing started. At first I thought the weird character thing was a bug in Konsole, but the blank screen appears on any application.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have this problem on my Ubuntu 16.04 with GNOME just since recently, approx. 2 weeks. I can't figure out how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually the correct system behavior. This has nothing to do with your keyboard bindings in Gnome - you are dealing with a much lower-level part of the system, which is independent of Gnome and friends.

Alt-F1 through Alt-F7 (and I suspect, Alt+Arrow) are configured to switch between Linux Virtual Terminals (VTs) and in most cases, Xorg will be running on VT7. On many systems, VT1-VT4 may contain a text-based login prompt, but this is not always the case. VTs can be useful if your main X session dies, and you need a way to log in and clean things up.

I recommend leaving these settings be, but if you are REALLY interested in remapping Alt+F1 to something different, you could try to modify your init to disable these keybindings. The place where they live will be specific to your distribution, but common locations include /etc/inittab or maybe /etc/console-setup/remap.inc

Now... if you press Alt-F1 and you see a totally blank screen, rather than a text login prompt, it could mean that virtual terminals are disabled on your system, or that your framebuffer console driver is broken, or that maybe your Xorg driver isn't playing nicely with your framebuffer driver. In the latter case I am afraid there is little that can be done via this forum, but if you really want this feature, you could try disabling the framebuffer console and switch to a legacy text console instead. I haven't had to do the latter in a long time, but you can try adding either 'nofb' or 'vga=normal' to your kernel command line. This will not unbind the Alt+F1 keybindings, but it may improve what you see when you press them.